# Travelling for religious purpose

Tags: grammar

While praying for traveling in order to promote religious education if we want God to give us ability and feasibility, if we say:
May we be enable to travel in God's path!
May we be enable to travel on God's path!
Are these two right?

Answer (score 1):

*May we be **enabled** to travel **on** God's path!*

Perhaps, it's even better to say ***following*** God's path...